# Use xcconfig string list in info.plist array

Tags: ios

How can I reference a list of strings defined in an .xcconfig file and expose it in my info.plist variables?

Say I have a list of names in my `.xcconfig`:

```
PLAYER_NAMES = "Bob" "Jorge" "Susan" "Dani"
```

When I look at my project's Build Settings -> User Defined section I see a key called `PLAYER_NAMES`. The value seems to show multiple strings:

```
"Bob" "Jorge" "Susan" "Dani"
```

I would like to access this from my app at run-time. To my knowledge the best way to do this is add an entry into `info.plist`. The issue I hit is I do not know how to reference the string list. I really do not want to have an individual variable for each name in this list so I actually do want the list itself.

I've read up on how to this with simpler values that are not lists, but am stumped on how to do this for a list value.

TLDR:
How can I put the contents of a string list called `PLAYER_NAMES` from a `.xcconfig` into my `info.plist` so that I can access it in the app at runtime via `Bundle.main.infoDictionary["PLAYER_NAMES"]` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best alternative I've found is to convert the list into a CSV string and then I can reference that in my `info.plist` values. I can then use `String.split` to get the resulting list of strings. This really does not seem ideal as this string list type exists in `.xcconfig` files so there has to be some way to use it, but I'm out of ideas.

`info.plist`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PLAYER_NAMES</key>
    <string>$(PLAYER_NAMES)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`App.swift`

```swift
guard let pListDict: [String: Any] = Bundle.main.infoDictionary else {
   fatalError("PList file not found")
}

// Assumes that build has a variable named "PLAYER_NAMES" in info.plist
let playerNames = (pListDict["PLAYER_NAMES"] as! String).split(separator: ",")
```